# Ubuntu 16.04 not outputting audio to earbuds

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, alsa, headphones, audio-jack

I dual boot Windows 8 and Ubuntu 16.04.

`pavucontrol` shows that I have the following two ports on my "built-in audio analog stereo": "Speakers" and "Line-Out (unplugged)."

The Speakers option works fine. The Line-Out option does not work. It continues to say that it is unplugged regardless of whether or not my earbuds are plugged in.

The configuration that I am using is "Analog Stereo Duplex."

Alternating "Auto-Mute" between Enabled and Disabled does not seem to work on `alsamixer`.

I'm not sure what else to try, any help is greatly appreciated.